# Portable alternatives to random_device for seeding pseudo-RNG?

Tags: c++, random

So, I've come across some answers and comments about `random_device` either being bugged or it purposefully using a deterministic method as a fallback when a non-deterministic method can't be used on the implementation.

As a matter of fact, I'm on Windows using GCC and I can't use `random_device` because of that problem (every created instance returns the same number). I know you could use `time()` but this isn't ideal either as seeds are identical when created in the same second.

What are portable alternatives that can be used for seeding PRNG?

Comment: You can use Boost, I don't know about all the platforms that it supports, but it will solve your problem on Windows

Comment: Depends on how you define "portable". In my ojrandlib, for example, I detect what OS I'm running on and use CryptGenRandom() if I'm on Windows and /dev/urandom if I'm on Linux/Mac.